# Show that $R$ a subring of $M_3(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

> Let $R =\left \{  \begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &a  &b \\ 
>  0& 0 & c\\ 
>  0&  0& 0
> \end{pmatrix}:a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}\right \}$ . Show that $R$ a subring of $M_3(\mathbb{R})$. Is it a ring with identity? If so, is it a unital subring.

Clearly, the zero matrix lies in $R$. Also,

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 &a_1  &b_1 \\ 
 0& 0 & c_1\\ 
 0&  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}- \begin{pmatrix}
0 &a_2  &b_2 \\ 
 0& 0 & c_2\\ 
 0&  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 &a_1-a_2  &b_1-b_2 \\ 
 0& 0 & c_1-c_2\\ 
 0&  0& 0
\end{pmatrix} \in R $$

and

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 &a_1  &b_1 \\ 
 0& 0 & c_1\\ 
 0&  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
0 &a_2  &b_2 \\ 
 0& 0 & c_2\\ 
 0&  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 &0  &a_1c_2 \\ 
 0& 0 & 0\\ 
 0&  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}\in R $$

Is it a ring with identity? I do not think so, since the product of these matrices are a subset of $R$ and thus, there is no matrix $I$, such that $AI=IA=A$ for all $A\in R$. Am I right?

Finally, whether or not there is an identity matrix, we have that $R$ is not a unital subring. Since identity in $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ is  $\begin{pmatrix}
1&0  &0 \\ 
 0& 1 & 0\\ 
 0&  0& 1
\end{pmatrix}\notin R$.

Comment: I think you don't have to post this, because you already understood it. The ring of strictly-upper triangular matrices is discussed here at this site already.

Comment: I think you may want to be careful about the unital part. You can have subrings which has a different unital element. For example, $R=2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't look like a unital ring but $4=1_R$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde There are many things that I think I understood, but when I post them here, it turns out that they were complete nonsense. I study completely alone. You are my teachers :(

Comment: @daruma This is the definition of **unital subring** from my book. "Let $R$ be a ring with identity $1$. Then a subring $S$ of $R$ is said to be
a unital subring if $1 ∈ S$."

Comment: Ah, I see so in your case you need to be careful when arguing whether it is a ring with identity. i.e. They are making the distinction between a ring with identity and a unital subring. So $2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ would not be a unital subring of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ but it is nevertheless a ring with an identity.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good.  As per the comment below, there are ways for a subring to have an identity, but your proof of closure under multiplication also proves there is no unit element,  as you can't have anything preserve positions $a$ and $c$ for nonzero values.

Comment: @rschwieb Got it, updated answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Your reasons for the first and third parts are fine, but not the second:

> Is it a ring with identity? I do not think so, since the product of these matrices are a subset of  and thus, there is no matrix , such that == for all ∈. Am I right?

Merely being a subset of $R$ does not preclude a subring from having its own identity. The identity $e$ of any ring always satisfies $e^2=e$, that is, it is idempotent.  In fact, if you have any such element $e\in R$, then $eRe$ is always a subring with identity $e$.

But let's keep going with this fact that $e^2=e$. Note that in the ring in question, $x^3=0$ for every element $x$.  It should be obvious to you now that nothing is going to satisfy $e^2=e$ except $0$, which is clearly not the identity.